# Pass data from redmine to wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, redmine, redmine-plugins

How to pass data from Redmine to WCF? I need to trigger a call to execute a C# application remotely from Redmine.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @asettouf i donot have any hint how  to do it. To view and insert data in redmine for bug reporting from a c# application we do have redmine .net api. But for the passing custom data from redmine (for example on a button click) to wcf (to trigger an operation on receiving data here) i couldnot find any solution